# How do I combine regular Munchkin with Munchkin Zombies?

Tags: munchkin

I have Munchkin 1 & 2 and recently I was given Munchkin Zombies. At the instructions of the latter, it is said that I combine these three (any kind of Munchkin to be honest), but it doesn't say how.

How can I combine Munchkin 1 & 2 with Munchkin Zombies 1?

Comment: Isn't it just a case of shuffling all the cards together?

Comment: Not really. How do you turn into a zombie?

Comment: I never played Zombies, but I would guess you all start as Zombies. Some help may be found here: http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/#m7b. It aswers the questions and provides a link to rules to a set that is used when combining sets :D

Answer (score 4):

Shuffle them all together.

That is why this is a great gateway game but unfortunately it is also a little silly since so many cards have different backings when they are added to the core set. (Sorry, personal opinion)

You are a zombie - that is how you start, you have no powers when there is no mojo - you can discard a mojo to become a plain zombie.

Shuffle, deal.

Comment: I'd like to add that Munchkin Blender (http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/blender/) is specifically designed to shuffle in with your other decks and alleviate some common problems with combining decks. That said, any two (or more) munchkin sets can be mixed, and some of my best experiences with the game come from combining 4 or more base sets, even without blender.